# assigning values in for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, assign

This might be a stupid question...but I cannot get the way to do this...

I want to do something like this, here you can see what I have tried:

```
value, value1 = [i,i+1 for i in range(5)] ---> failed
(value, value1) = [(i,i+1) for i in range(5)] ---> failed
value, value1 = [[i,i+1] for i in range(5)] ---> failed
```

It is just an attempt to assign 2 values in a loop, quite basic.

I do not know if can be done like that, I guess so.

NOTE that I am not interested at all in the values of i, or in the numbers showed in the example etc. I am just looking for a way to assign 2 values.

**EDIT:**

If that helps, what I was trying to get as output would be: (Im using python 2.7)

```
value, value1 = [i,i+1 for i in range(5)]
```

then the output will be

```
value = [0,1,2,3,4]
value1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: `quite basic` I don't understand what you are expecting as output, so no I would not say it is "basic"

Comment: You're creating a single list and are trying to unpack it; that is, `val1, val2 = [(1, 2), (2, 3)]` will result in `val1 = (1,2)` and `val2 = (2,3)`

Comment: well, the OP made it clear: *I am just looking for a way to assign 2 values.*

Comment: I do not think that It was unclear, I do not tknow why is it marked as unclear. I think it is quite stright forward.....A SIMPLE WAY TO ASIGN 2 VALUES USING ONE SINGLE FOR LOOP. I really do not understand why is it marked as unclear. I think most of the users understood it...mostly when it got several answers

Comment: Assigning two values is easy. _What those values are_ is where it's unclear, though the example helps tremendously.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create two lists to do what you are trying to do.

```
In [4]: value, value1 = [i for i in range(5)],[j for j in range(5)]

In [5]: value
Out[5]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

In [6]: value1
Out[6]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks Padraic, I knew that of course, but the reason for using (or to try to use) only 1 `for` loop is because, in this case, is a short loop, but what would happen in the same situation with `... in range(100000000)`, it would have to loop over 100000000 two times, which would be less efficient if Im not wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop over the values, you can use the `zip` function, as such:

```
for i,j in zip(range(5), range(1,6)):
    print(i,j)
```

This will work efficiently for large ranges, as there are no lists that need allocation.

If you actually want two lists, then the best (by which I mean clearest) way to do it is with two loops:

```
val1, val2 = [i for i in range(5)], [i for i in range(1,6)]
```

Large lists are going to be inefficient no matter what you do.

Comment: Colonel, i WANT NOTHING with `value` and `value1`....it was just an EXAMPLE, it could have been something like `value, value1 = [i*3,(i*5-6) for i in range(5)]` it doesn't matter at all, the point was how to give them any value using one single for loop

Comment: @user2919052 Calm down. I'm using that as an example too.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the first tuple as two values, using several ways:

by using list subscription:

```
value, value1 = [(i,i+1) for i in range(5)][0]
```

which is by far the most readable and simple way to go.

by using destructuring assignment:

```
(value, value1), _, _, _, _ = [(i,i+1) for i in range(5)]
```

or using python3 you can:

```
(value, value1), *_ = [(i,i+1) for i in range(5)]
```

The `_` is a variable placeholder that discards the value when unpacking. The `*` works the same way as for arguments, which means stands for a completing list of values, though it's a novelty introduced in python3, which is why in python2 you need to place as many `_` as there are values in your list.

The destructuring assignment is some syntax sugar that enable to do something like the following:

```
>>> [[a,b],c,d],e,f = [[[1,2],3,4],5,6]
>>> print a,b,c,d,e,f
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for assigning multiple variable in one line is:

```
variable_1, variable_2 = value_1, value_2
```

In your example you are only providing a value for the first variable.

Comment: Why the downvote? The OP made it clear in his question that he wasn't interested in the values in his example he just wanted to know how to assign 2 values.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than just "it failed" which is of no use to anyone including yourself, you should look at the error message.

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

So it expects 2, as I would expect since you're trying to assign values to two variables, but you should be asking yourself why there are too many values.

An easy way is to simply print out what you're trying to assign, and throwing in a print statement shows

```
[[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]]
```

If you are not interested in the value of `i`, and are only interested in "how to assign two values", you need to clarify WHICH two values you want.

For example you could just as well say

```
value, value1 = [[i,i+1] for i in range(5)][-1]
```

If you just want the last one to be stored since you are not interested in the list anyways apparently. You might as well just say

```
value, value1 = 1,2
```

If you want to convince yourself that it is possible to assign multiple variables in a single statement.

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking about it wrong. You are trying to assign too many variables at a single time, not that you can't do it. Its just you're formating is incorrect.

You probably thought of something like this

```
value, value1 = [i,i+1 for i in range(5)] ---> failed
```

Assuming it did not fail you would of thought; 
This will give me the following values:

```
value, value1 = [0,1,2,3,4]
and value = [0,1,2,3,4]
```

And if you read the error, its a Value Error; too many to unpack **"expected 2"** different values.

x1, y1 = x2, y2

is the proper formatting where **x1 = x2 and y1 = y2.**